# items successfully deleted in listview but causes infinite loop when updating the remaining items in the listview

Tags: vb.net, vba

Hi again i was able to successfully deleted items in the my listbox which is not yet check-out but when i was updating my database using the remaining items in the listview it yields infinite loop. the problem is at the line where i update the remaining in my listview it only updates the first line and do not loop on the next line.

```
Dim ListOfExistingItem As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    Try
        For x = 0 To ListView2.Items.Count - 1
            Dim a As String = ListView2.Items.Item(x).Text
            a = ListView2.Items.Item(x).Text

            '-------------------------Max TRansaction----------------------------------
            Dim SQLMAX As String = ("Select Max(transaction_no) from tbl_list1 where barcode = '" + a + "' and [Check-In] IS NULL and [User] = '" + rsuser + "'")
            Dim STRMAX As String = ""

            Dim cmdmax As New SqlCommand(SQLMAX, locconn)
            Dim MAXREAD As SqlDataReader

            locconn.Open()
            MAXREAD = cmdmax.ExecuteReader
            MAXREAD.Read()
            If IsDBNull(MAXREAD(0)) = False Then
                STRMAX = MAXREAD(0)
            End If
            MAXREAD.Close()
            locconn.Close()
            '-----Remove items to listview that are not yet checked out-------------------------------------

            Dim sqlvalreader As SqlDataReader
            Dim TMP_SQL_VAL2 = "select [Check-In] from tbl_list1 where barcode = '" + a + "' and transaction_no = '" & STRMAX & "'"
            Dim cmdval = New SqlCommand(TMP_SQL_VAL2, locconn)
            locconn.Open()
            sqlvalreader = cmdval.ExecuteReader
            sqlvalreader.Read()



            If sqlvalreader.HasRows Then
                If IsDBNull(sqlvalreader(0)) = False Then
                    MsgBox("Barcode: " & a & "is still Inside", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                    clear_text()
                    ListOfExistingItem.Add(x)
                End If
            Else
                ListOfExistingItem.Add(x)
            End If
            sqlvalreader.Close()
            locconn.Close()
        Next
        Call ListOfExistingItem.Reverse()
        If Not IsNothing(ListOfExistingItem) Then
            For Each x As Integer In ListOfExistingItem
                If Not x > ListView2.Items.Count - 1 Then
                    ListView2.Items.RemoveAt(x)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




    '-------------------------update the remaining items in the listview-----------------------

    Try

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim a, b, c, d As String
        For i = 0 To ListView2.Items.Count - 1
            a = ListView2.Items.Item(i).Text
            b = ListView2.Items.Item(i).SubItems.Item(1).Text
            c = ListView2.Items.Item(i).SubItems.Item(2).Text
            d = ListView2.Items.Item(i).SubItems.Item(3).Text
            i = i - 1


            Dim SQLMAX As String = ("Select Max(transaction_no) from tbl_list1 where barcode = '" + a + "' and [Check-In] IS NULL and [User] = '" + rsuser + "'")
            Dim STRMAX As String = ""

            Dim cmdmax As New SqlCommand(SQLMAX, locconn)
            Dim MAXREADER As SqlDataReader

            locconn.Open()
            MAXREADER = cmdmax.ExecuteReader
            MAXREADER.Read()
            If IsDBNull(MAXREADER(0)) = False Then
                STRMAX = MAXREADER(0)
            End If

            locconn.Close()

            Dim command As New SqlCommand
            TMP_SQL = "update tbl_list1 " & _
                      "set [Check-In] = GETDATE() " & _
                      "where ID_ = (select top (1) ID_ " & _
                      "from tbl_list1 " & _
                      "where barcode = '" + a + "' and transaction_no = '" + STRMAX + "' and [Check-In] IS NULL) "

            locconn.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(TMP_SQL, locconn)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            locconn.Close()
        Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line is suspicious, just try to remove it :

```
i = i - 1
```

`i` is a counter variable in the `For` loop. It expected to be incremented on every iteration so that at some point `i` value will reach upper bound of the loop which is `ListView2.Items.Count - 1`. Since above code decrement value of `i` back, it never reach the upper bound, hence causing infinite loop.

If you are not convinced by the explanation above, just try this in a new console application :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 100
    i = i - 1
Next
Console.WriteLine("Finish loop")
```

The application will never print "Finish loop", but as soon as you remove `i = i - 1` line you can see the output right away. So if your loop was somehow terminated in some situation, then the proper question is "*why it was not infinite when it should? There must be some strange behavior that caused it worked*" instead of the opposite "*why this loop is infinite?*"

That's what I think :)

Comment: should i just remove it? when i was not deleting item from listview that update line works perfectly i suspect it has something to with listview behavior when an item is deleted

Comment: I'm not sure why that happened. But from the codes you provide, i can't see the use of `i = i-1`, so that another reason to remove it. I can't find `i` variable used in any line after it decremented.

Comment: try to remove try-catch to see if any error happened, just an idea

Comment: oh i i get it :) thx i was using do while on my example and on my prog i was using for loop sorry my bad :)